# How to reorder dstack

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have 6 files with shape (6042,) or 1 column. I used dstack to stack the 6 files in hopes of getting a shape (6042, 1, 6). But after I stack it I get shape (1, 6042, 6). Then I tried to change the order using

```
new_train = np.reshape(train_x,(train_x[1],1,train_x[2]))
```

error appears:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

This is my dstack code:

```
train_x = dstack([train_data['gx'],train_data['gy'], train_data['gz'], train_data['ax'],train_data['ay'], train_data['az']])
```

Comment: `np.stack(x_train, axis=1)[:,None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is because

```
train_x[1]
```

tries looking 2nd row of train_x but it has only 1 row as you said shape 1, 6042, 6). So you need to look shape and index it

```
new_train = np.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[1], 1, train_x.shape[2]))
```

but this can be also doable with transpose

```
new_train = train_x.transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

so this changes axes 0 and 1's positions.

Other solution is fixing dstack's way. It gives "wrong" shape because your datas shape not (6042, 1) but (6042,) as you say. So if you reshape the datas before dstack it should also work:

```
datas = [train_data['gx'],train_data['gy'], train_data['gz'],
         train_data['ax'],train_data['ay'], train_data['az']]

#this list comprehension makes all shape (6042, 1) now
new_datas = [td[:, np.newaxis] for td in datas]

new_train = dstack(new_datas)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.moveaxis(X, 0, -2)`, where `X` is your `(1,6042,6)` array.

This function swaps the axis. `0` for your source axis and `-2` is your destination axis.

Answer (score 0):

`np.dstack` uses:

```
arrs = atleast_3d(*tup)
```

to convert the list of arrays to a list of 3d arrays.

```
In [51]: alist = [np.ones(3,int),np.zeros(3,int)]
In [52]: alist
Out[52]: [array([1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0])]
In [53]: np.atleast_3d(*alist)
Out[53]: 
[array([[[1],
         [1],
         [1]]]),
 array([[[0],
         [0],
         [0]]])]
In [54]: _[0].shape
Out[54]: (1, 3, 1)
```

Concatenating those on the last dimension produces the (1,n,6) kind of result.

With `expand_dims` we can adjust the shape of all arrays to (n,1,1), and then do the concatenate:

```
In [62]: np.expand_dims(alist[0],[1,2]).shape
Out[62]: (3, 1, 1)
In [63]: np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(a,[1,2]) for a in alist], axis=2)
Out[63]: 
array([[[1, 0]],

       [[1, 0]],

       [[1, 0]]])
In [64]: _.shape
Out[64]: (3, 1, 2)
```

direct reshape or `newaxis` would work just as well:

```
In [65]: np.concatenate([a[:,None,None] for a in alist], axis=2).shape
Out[65]: (3, 1, 2)
```

`stack` is another cover that adjusts shapes before concatenate:

```
In [67]: np.stack(alist,1).shape
Out[67]: (3, 2)
In [68]: np.stack(alist,1)[:,None].shape
Out[68]: (3, 1, 2)
```

So there are lots of ways to get what you want, whether it means adjusting shapes before the concatenate, or after.